# Using preg_replace() to truncate a string AFTER a .com or .net or .org

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need to write a chunk of code that looks at a user's `HTTP_REFERER` and if the referer is set, looks in a MySQL table to see whether or not the referer matches a domain we have registered in our database. Here's some sample code:

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
   $domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
   $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","database");

   $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT  `domain`, `affiliate_id`
     FROM  `affiliates`
     WHERE `domain` = '$domain'");

     $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
     Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->set('affiliate-cookie', $row['affiliate_id'], 0);
     mysqli_close($con);

}
```

The line here I need help is: `$domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];` What I need `$domain` to contain is JUST the domain of the referer, NOT the whole referer. So instead of: http://www.somesite.com/affiliate-page.html, it would strip it down, ideally, to just somesite.com, though I can live with it stripping it down to http://www.somesite.com if that's not possible.

I'm utterly crap at regex, but I can google. Unfortunately I haven't been able to find an example of a regex that truncates a string in up to three conditions. Any assistance would be wonderful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even better than a regexp, to parse a URL : [parse_url()](http://php.net/parse_url) . Give it a try.

```
echo parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_HOST);
```

Comment: +1 for parse_url(), but you still need to solve your TLD problem if you want the domain.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with regex but try [this](https://www.php.net/parse_url) first

I also suggest reading a bit about SQL injections in PHP and how to avoid them.

Comment: I may be ignorant here, but as the user is unable to input anything directly via a form, do I still need to worry about PHP injections? Can the user do harm by messing with the value of their referer?

Second, as I'm building this in to our Magento install, if I really want to not be lazy I can route it through Mage's core channels and that protects from injection. This is the lazy way. ;)

Comment: A hacker doesn't use a browser, isn't a user and crafts her own headers. Referer is a HTTP header, you can set simply by telnetting to the webserver. I'm not sure Magento sanitizes the referer, since it doesn't do anything useful with it.

Comment: Is there any way to sanitize the referer myself?

Comment: The question is sanitize for what? In your case, it's the DB, so use prepared statements and sanitize as normal.

Comment: @Seff - Do you have any recommendations? This is largely new territory for me, so I'm not totally sure where to start.

Comment: It's like Melvyn said, Magento already has a database connection and a request object you can use. For more information on that go to the link I'm editing into my reply. I'll also write up a short guide on how to do it without Magento if you like.

Comment: I really appreciate the info. This site has been kind to this beginner. :) I'll let you know if I have more questions once I get a chance to read your edits.

Answer (score 2):

Sidenote: when using Magento, you already have a database connection and a request object you can use.

The basics are this:

```
$domain = preg_replace('#^https?://.*?\.([a-z0-9\-]+\.[a-z]{2,})/.*$#', '$1', $req->referer);
```

Your challenge is in the TLD and you probably can best solve this using preg_replace_callback() and integrate the [public suffix list](http://publicsuffix.org/list/).

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for http://[anything]/, and you want it to match everything before the trailing /

Solution: `/(http:\/\/)([^\/]*)(?=\/)/`

`[^\/]*` is 0 or more characters that are not /

`?=` is look ahead, so the trailing slash is not included

To get this into your database, you can use Magento's built in functions. More information here:
[Magento Info](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table)

If you would rather do it yourself and have php 5 installed I recommend using PDO.

Here is a guide on its usage: [PDO Tutorial 1](http://mikerogers.io/2011/07/01/pdo-php-data-objects-starter-guide.html)

Here is a more in depth guide: [PDO Tutorial 2](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)

Here is an example of its usage: [PDO Example](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PDO-Insert-and-Update-Statement-Use-Prepared-Statement-P552.html)

For your project you'll want to get the URL from the header then tart a database connection.
insert the url into the database. Close the connection. No sanitation is necessary for PDO because it uses prepared statements.

If you can't use PDO for whatever reason, look up [mysqli](http://codular.com/php-mysqli). It also uses prepared statements. If you can't use that either, use `$sanitized_string = mysql_real_escape_string($string);` to sanitize the url and make sure you only use `$sanitized_string` with the database.